# How do I create a kick command for a discord bot?

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

Hello people that have viewed this. I need help on creating a kick command for my discord bot. I am using `discord.js` and `node.js` . I do have the starting things like `const Discord = require('discord.js');` `const Client = new Discord.Client();` . I am coding it using Visual Studio Code. I don't really understand what else to do. I've tried looking for help in YouTube, but every time I try it seems to not work anymore. Can someone please guide me? Thanks :D

Comment: So you only have that 2 lines of codes? Try refer to the examples in `discord.js` documentations https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/ping

Answer (score 0):

The greate guild its https://discordjs.guide, you can find all information here.

The one way to create kick command its use this code. But the kick command is quite complicated for a novice user. It needs to take into account many nuances, try to implement something simpler to begin with.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startWith('!kick') {
        if(message.channel.type === 'DM') {
            //Fist check if message channel is not direct message, because you cant kick out of guide 
            message.channel.send('This command can use only in guide');
            return;
        };

        //Then check if user have permissions to do that
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
            message.channel.send('You have no permissions to do that');
            return;
        };

        //const a member, wich you need yo kick (its fist mention message member)
        let mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        //If user dont mention a member, that show him this error msg
        if(!mentionMember) {
            message.channel.send('pls mention member witch you need to kick');
            return;
        }

        //Get the highest role of user for compare
        let authorHighestRole = message.member.highestRole.position;
        let mentionHighestRole = mentionMember.highestRole.position;

        //If mention user have same or higher role, so show this error msg
        if(mentionHighestRole >= authorHighestRole) {
            message.channel.send('You can`t kick members with equal or higher position');
            return;
        };

        //Check if your bot can`t kick this user, so that show this error msg 
        if(!mentionMember.kickable) {
            message.channel.send('I have no permissions to kick this user');
            return
        };

        //If all steps are completed successfully try kick this user
        mentionMember.kick()
            .then(() => console.log(`Kicked ${member.displayName}`))
            .catch(console.error);
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here...

```
    client.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // If the message content starts with "!kick"
  if (message.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
    // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Kick the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         */
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            // We let the message author know we were able to kick the person
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to kick the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
  }
});
```

(from discord.js github)

Answer (score -1):

idk if (content == 'kick') {
let user = msg.mentions.members.first()
if(!user) return msg.reply('Please mention a user, that't has to be removed from the guild!')//Why? I write in grammar! *It's discord nothing makes sense!*
if(!user.kickable){
db.set(`Kicked-${msg.guild.id}`, {userId: user.id, userTag: user.user.tag, guildId: msg.guild.id, guildName: msg.guild.name, modId: msg.author.id, modName: msg.author.name,isKicked: kicked})
return msg.reply('The user isn't kickable!')

kicked = false
}
db.set(`Kicked-${msg.guild.id}`, {userId: user.id, userTag: user.user.tag, guildId: msg.guild.id, guildName: msg.guild.name, modId: msg.author.id, modName: msg.author.name,isKicked: kicked})
kicked = true

```
    user.kick('Kicked was by ' + msg.author.tag)
```

}

if(content == 'test'){
let modname =    db.get(`Kicked-${msg.guild.id}`).modName
msg.reply(modname)
}